# Preencher matriz com ZERO nos espaços nulos, (python/django)

Tags: javascript, python, django, bootstrap

O problema esta nas partes marcadas em **vermelho**, não estou conseguindo atribuir zeros a ela.
De acordo com modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*O trecho do código que estou gerando esta tabela:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs:* A seleção deste período pode variar de acordo com a seleção: (ex. 2016 até 2017/ 2015 até 2017...)

Comment: É mais difícil verificar seu problema quando se coloca código como imagem. Poderia editar sua pergunta colando o código JS? (Isso pode ser feito clicando na imagem do papel com <> ao lado de inserir imagem)

Answer (score 0):

Se as variáveis `somatorio.3` e `somatorio.2` estiverem apresentando o valor `None`, você pode usar o filtro [`default_if_none`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) para traduzí-los para zero.

No seu caso ficaria assim:

```
<td class="text-center">{{ somatorio.3|default_if_none:"0" }}({{ somatorio.2|default_if_none:"0" }})</td>
```

Comment: Cara tentei aqui e não rolo com default_if_none:"0". Ele segue igual.

Comment: Certamente o motivo é que `somatorio.3` e `somatorio.2` não possuem o valor `None`, ou seja, não são  valores nulos como vc colocou na sua pergunta.